# multiple image upload loop only adding one image id and path database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

Hi every one I am trying to create an mvc application that allows the user to upload multiple photos to a folder and saves the Id and path in the database. Currently my application adds all the files to the folder but only adds the last selected image id and path to the database.

Thanks for any help with this problem

### View

```
 @using (Html.BeginForm("Create", "Home", null, FormMethod.Post,
                                                              new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
        {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            @Html.ValidationSummary(true)
            <fieldset>

                <legend>Image</legend>
                <form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

                    <div class="editor-label">
                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.ImagePath)

                    </div>
                    <div class="editor-field">
                        <input id="ImagePath" title="Upload a product image" multiple="multiple" type="file" name="files" />

                        @*<img class="img-thumbnail" width="150" height="150" src="@Url.Action("GetImage", "Home",new { Model.ID })" />*@
                    </div>
                    <p><input type="submit" value="Create" /></p>
                </form>
            </fieldset>
        }
        <div>
```

### Controller

```
public ViewResult Create()
            {
                return View("Create", new Image());

            }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Create(Image Image, IEnumerable<HttpPostedFileBase> files)
        {

         if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {


            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                {

                    file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Img/") + file.FileName);
                    Image.ImagePath = file.FileName;

                }
                repository.Create(Image);
            }
           }
           return RedirectToAction("Index");

        }
```

### Model

```
public partial class Image
{
    [Key]
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string ImagePath { get; set; }
}
```

EFRepositoty

```
public void  Create(Image Image)
            {


                if (Image.ID == 0)
                {
                    context.Images.Add(Image);
                }
                else
                {
                    Image dbEntry = context.Images.Find(Image.ID);
                    if (dbEntry != null)
                    {
                        dbEntry.ImagePath = Image.ImagePath;

                    }
                }
                context.SaveChanges();

        }
```

Comment: You need to create a new `Image` in each iteration - currently you keep overwriting the `ImagePath` property (the first iteration adds it, and subsequent iterations update the same row in the database)

Comment: Thank you for your help you have solved my issue

Comment: You really should delete you `Create()` method or rename it to say `Save()` (it both creates and updates)

Comment: thanks Stephen for the advice I will rename it,  just checking before i do it  its EFRepositoty create() method you are saying to rename or should I consider renaming the controller methods by the same name also .

Comment: No, your controller method is 'Creating' images, but your `public void  Create(Image Image)` both creates and updates (if the ID is not `0`).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because you are redirecting to index inside your loop so it only processes the first file. Move your ModelState.IsValid check outside of the loop

```
if(!ModelState.IsValud)
    return View();
```

And then put redirect to last line of method.

What's happening with the Image entity is when its saved the first time the object is given an ID then for each other file in the loop it's just updating the same record in the database, this is why you will only see the last file in the db.

At the end of each loop you should set the image = null will fix things.

Comment: Hi Matt thanks for your help I have got it so that now it adds both files to the folder but for some reason it only adds the last file that was selected to the db(I have updated the post with the new create method) .

Comment: Updated my answer. Please accept my answer once you've got it working. :-)

Answer (score 0):

The solution I used was based on Stephens comment although Matts is an equally good solution:

```
                    Image image = new Image();
                    if (file.ContentLength > 0)
                    {
                        file.SaveAs(HttpContext.Server.MapPath("~/Img/") + file.FileName);
                        image.ImagePath = file.FileName;
                    }
                    repository.Create(image);
```